# How can I convert repetitive fragments into one to handle them

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 8 fragments which are similar between each other. I want to make a general fragment to manage all of these. I don´t have a clear idea how to acchieve this idea.

My fragments have the same code, except layout, and 2 or 3 methods. So, I think that the best way is to have this in one fragment for all.

What is the best way.

Fragment 1.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.lm_fragment, container, false);
   }

   public void method(){}
}
```

Fragment 2.

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.lm_fragment, container, false);
   }

   public void method2(){}

   public void method3(){}
}
```

Fragment X...

Every fragment has the same structure, only changes between them in the methods of each fragment.

I want to do:

General Fragment to manage all cases, with a helper with the methods or something like that.

Comment: please post the code for this question

Answer (score 0):

use any key like int value and pass that value to getInstance() menthod of fragment and then get that value in onCreateView() and inflate respective layout. problem solve

Comment: Ok, I take the idea, but what I can do with the methods? In some fragments I have 5 or 6 methods. So, I need to write out of the general fragment.

Comment: based on the int arg you passed to fragment, you can decide which method to call or not. include all method in one fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In your base fragment class add an abstract method that is

```
public int layoutId() {

return R.layout.fragment2_layout;

}
```

In your subclasses override that method and return the respective layout.

In your onCreateView you will use the layoutId() method.

```
@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  return inflater.inflate(layoutId(), container, false);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance.

Eg. Create a BaseFragment which contains all the common methods.

Then all your other specialized fragments classes that have special methods just extends this BaseFragment.

Eg.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.lm_fragment, container, false);
   }

   public void commonMethod(){}
}


public class SpecialFragment extends BaseFragment {

   public void specialMethod2(){}

   public void specialMethod3(){}
}
```

Comment: I agree with this. On Android, it's not easy (or advisable) to make a fragment that manages several other fragments (i.e. using composition). In this case it's much easier to use inheritance.

Comment: This is the case that I have. What I want is a Fragment to manage some views (layout). But the problem is that the fragments have a lot of methods. If I put them inside one fragment, the file could be enormous. I'm asking for a helper with the methods or something.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "want a Fragment to manage some views (layout)" ? What do you need to the different fragments to do to the view?